# react on a supply from a sequence

Tags: sequence, raku

I can't understand why this program works:

```
my $supply = Supply.interval: 1;

react {
  whenever $supply       { put "Got $^a"  }
  whenever Promise.in(5) { put 'Timeout!'; done }
}

END put 'Ending…'
```

printing this:

```
Got 0
Got 1
Got 2
Got 3
Got 4
Timeout!
Ending…
```

and exits correctly, while this one:

```
my $supply = (1, 1, * + * … ∞).Supply;

react {
  whenever $supply       { put "Got $^a"; sleep 1 }
  whenever Promise.in(5) { put 'Timeout!'; done }
}

END put 'Ending…'
```

prints

```
Got 1
Got 1
Got 2
Got 3
Got 5
Timeout!
```

but then it hangs and doesn't output the "Ending…"; isn't the "done" enough in this case?

If I replace "done" with "exit" the program works fine and exits.

Comment: I'd have to think this through more thoroughly, but one of the differences is that there's more stuff in the supply in the second case, while in the first case, you are effectively stopping the production as soon as you call done. This is probably a case of underdocumentation of `done`, but it might go in that direction. Also, Seq.Supply creates a list. https://docs.perl6.org/routine/Supply#(Any)_method_Supply Don't know how that will go with the infinite sequence...

Comment: Seems like the deadlock is related to the infinite sequence, since if I replace with `my $supply = (^10).Supply` it works fine.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I thought that Supply.interval was an infinite sequence too, since it returns an increasing value and it goes on forever.

Comment: @FernandoSantagata it's not really an infinite sequence; it's going to produce new elements as long as the supply is not done.